# How can I make a Sublime Text project file to only show certain folders?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

SublimeText has a [project-settings file](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html) that includes a `folder_include_patterns` option.

I have a folder called `(my app name).project-settings` (which according to some research, is the correct name for the file) in the top level of my project. I am trying to make Sublime not show all the files under `node_modules` except `my-module`:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "node_modules",
      "folder_include_patterns": [
        "my-module"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However SublimeText still shows all the files under `node_modules`. **How can I make a Sublime Text project file to only show certain folders?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax is correct, but **making the file isn't enough to make a dir into a project.**

Since there is no 'new project' button in Sublime, you can make a folder with:

- Open the folder in Sublime.
- Click *Project > Save Project As*

This makes:

`your_project.sublime-project`

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    },
    {
      "path": "node_modules",
      "folder_include_patterns": [
        "my-module"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`your_project.sublime-workspace` (left as defaults)

Additionally: you must open the project from the Project menu (otherwise it will still be a folder and ignore the `.sublime-project` file).

Comment: Haha, yep, you need to open the project :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't want to ignore *all the other* modules in `node_modules`.
You could ignore your `node_modules` directory and include your module as another folder.

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "folder_exclude_patterns":
      [
        "node_modules",
      ],
      "path": "."
    },
    {
      "path": "node_modules/mymodule"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: I meant "exclude", you don't want to manually list them all. This is a valid alternative.

Comment: You will need to change the paths the reflect your setup. In my case, the project file is in the same directory as the folders I'm adding.

Comment: Checking this it looks like the syntax is correct, but 1) the other file required to make a dir into a project was missing 2) opening a projects dir is not the same as opening a project.

Comment: I feel bad for answering my own question here, you were very helpful - have an upvote.